# How to get root terminal? Also I have a problem a wrong character appears instead of @

Tags: keyboard-layout, windows-xp

Dual boot Windows/Ubuntu.

1. In Ubuntu, I cannot write the character '@'. When I try to do so, another character appears, so cannot email! Tried another keyboard, same problem - both are fine in Windows.
2. Cannot access a "root" terminal. Searched for file `menu.lst` but cannot access it (in order to change default boot system). Please help. (Running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS / Windows XP)

Comment: What character appears instead of @? It would also help to separate your questions into two posts.

Comment: This is more than one question its bettet to seperate between

Answer (score 2):

As for the root terminal -- as have been pointed out, open a regular terminal (press Win key, type "terminal", enter), and type `sudo -i`, then your own password. But beware, you can trash your system as root if you don't know what you are doing.

Something must be wrong with your language / keyboard settings.

1. What physical keyboard are you using? US, German, ...?
2. Go to *System -> Preferences -> Keyboard* to open the *Layouts* tab. Move the appropriate layout to the top.
   <sub>(in 12.04 - press the "Win" key, type "keyboard layout", Enter. Make sure that your layout matches your physical keyboard. There is a little icon of a keyboard below the options. If you click it, you will see what the chosen layout is. I assure you that the @ key is there, waiting for you to get pressed)</sub>

#### 10.04

[image]

#### 12.04

[image]